# Why Navigator in Compose giving Illegal Argument error?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

For Navigation I've `navigation.kt` which hold `Nav()` that is used to navigate.
There is also a helper function `give_route()` that take string then if the it is known (hardcoded) then give its route otherwise `page_not_found` route - string for `navController`

```
package com.<company_name.<app_name>

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.<company_name.<app_name>


// Class For function needed for Navigation

@Composable
fun Nav() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Address.Feed.route) {

        composable(Address.Feed.route)
        {
            feed(
                Navi = {add -> navController.navigate(give_route(add))}
            )

        }

    }



}



fun give_route(title: String): String {
    return when (title) {
        "Feed" -> Address.Feed.route
        "Question" -> Address.Question.route
        "Notice" -> Address.Notice.route
        "Status" -> Address.Status.route
        "DM" -> Address.DM.route
        "Chat" -> Address.Chat.route
        "Group_chat" -> Address.Group_chat.route
        "Notify" -> Address.Notify.route
        "Search" -> Address.Search.route
        "Profile" -> Address.Profile.route
        "Profile-Pvt" -> Address.Profile_Pvt.route
        "Profile-User" -> Address.Profile_User.route
        "Ratting" -> Address.Ratting.route
        "New - Text" -> Address.New_Text.route
        "New - Image" -> Address.New_Image.route
        "New - Video" -> Address.New_Video.route
        "New - Audio" -> Address.New_Audio.route
        "New - Other" -> Address.New_File.route
        else -> Address.page_not_found.route

    }
}
```

All routes string are stored in Sealed class `Address.kt`

```
package com.<company_name.<app_name>

sealed class Address(val route: String) {

    object Feed : Address("Feed")
    object Question : Address("Question")
    object Notice : Address("Notice")
    object Status : Address("Status")
    object DM : Address("DM")
    object Chat : Address("Chat")
    object Group_chat : Address("Group_chat")
    object Notify : Address("Notify")
    object Search : Address("Search")
    object Profile : Address("Profile")
    object Profile_Pvt : Address("Profile-Pvt")
    object Profile_User : Address("Profile-User")
    object Ratting : Address("Ratting")
    object New_Text : Address("New - Text")
    object New_Image : Address("New - Image")
    object New_Video : Address("New - Video")
    object New_Audio : Address("New - Audio")
    object New_File : Address("New - File")
    object page_not_found : Address("Page not found")



}
```

I'm running Nav() from MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Nav()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finall all `@Composable` fun. are in `Views/Pages.kt`. For the purpose of this question I've hiided all fun except `feed` and its Menyitem clled func, for ex. `New_Text`

```
package com.<company_name.<app_name>


import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.*
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*

// PAGE VIEWS


// Feed View
@Composable
fun feed(Navi: (String) -> Unit) {

    var newPost by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } // TODO - y

    Row() {
        FilledTonalIconButton(
            onClick = { newPost = true },
            enabled = true
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Rounded.Add,
                "Button for creating a new post. " +
                        "Opens the Menu to selct the type for your new post"
            )
        }

        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = newPost,
            onDismissRequest = { newPost = false }
        ) {
            DropdownMenuItem(
                text = { Text("Text") },
                onClick = { Navi("New - Text") },
                enabled = true,
                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Rounded.ViewHeadline,
                        "To Post Text"
                    )
                }
            )

            DropdownMenuItem(
                text = { Text("Image") },
                onClick = { Navi("New - Image") },
                enabled = true,
                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Rounded.Wallpaper,
                        "To Post Image"
                    )
                }
            )

            DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Video") },
                onClick = { Navi("New - Video") },
                enabled = true,
                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Rounded.Slideshow,
                        "To Post Video"
                    )
                }
            )

            DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Audio") },
                onClick = { Navi("New - Audio") },
                enabled = true,
                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Rounded.SpatialAudioOff,
                        "To Post Audio"
                    )
                }
            )

            DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Other") },
                onClick = { Navi("New - Other") },
                enabled = true,
                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Rounded.PostAdd,
                        "To open custom file window for posting user file"
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun New_Text() {
    Text("a")
}


@Composable
fun New_Image() {
    Text("b")
}


@Composable
fun New_Video() {
    Text("c")
}



@Composable
fun New_Audio() {
    Text("d")
}


@Composable
fun New_File() {
    Text("e")
}
```

For dependicies, imports, versions etc. please vist my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74585315/20603322)

When I'm running on my debugging device, the feed is getting drawn and Drop Down Menu is axpanding on click but as soon as I press any Menu Button, I get following Error and app Stops.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.<company_name.<app_name>, PID: 20633
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/New - Audio } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x78c8aacb) route=Feed}
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1664)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1984)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1979)
        at com.<company_name.<app_name>.NavigationKt$Nav$1$1$1.invoke(Navigation.kt:21)
        at com.<company_name.<app_name>.NavigationKt$Nav$1$1$1.invoke(Navigation.kt:20)
        at com.<company_name.<app_name>.views.PagesKt$feed$1$3$4$1.invoke(Pages.kt:69)
        at com.<company_name.<app_name>.views.PagesKt$feed$1$3$4$1.invoke(Pages.kt:69)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:153)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:222)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:566)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:456)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:469)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:394)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:314)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:301)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:301)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:301)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:301)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:183)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:102)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1329)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1275)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3170)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2846)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:15384)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6667)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6114)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6176)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6137)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6311)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6145)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6368)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6118)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6176)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6137)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6145)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6118)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9272)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:9223)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9172)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9415)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:276)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:186)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8355)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@4373ed0, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@5894ec9, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@9edf9ce, AndroidUiDispatcher@fc450ef]
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20633 SIG: 9
```

Sorry for long Post.

Edit: I answered it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74586990/20603322)

Peace!

Comment: It seems like you only have one screen in your `NavHost`'s navigation graph - `Address.Feed.route`, so that's the only destination you'll ever be able to `navigate` to. Where are you adding all of your other routes to the `NavHost`?

Comment: I noticed that too. And fixed it. I posted it in the answer. This question is solved. But my other question still exist. @ianhanniballake if you don't mind please take a look:  Link: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74585315/20603322)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the error. There were three errors. Error message even told us about the error.

In second line of error output:

`Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/New - Audio } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x78c8aacb) route=Feed}`

this lead me to fix first error:

> In `Address.kt`: remove "New - <name>", as route, with "New_name".
> ex. `object New_Image : Address("New - Image")` to `object New_Image : Address("New_Image")`

Then I found out that

> In `Navhost` I didn't created Composable function for those pages that were asked from Dropdown Menu in `feed` view

Last error was that It was creating impropoer build, which resolved on restarting. I suspect it was because of lack of Ram,  as before closing Android Studio was taking 5.something GB and Chrome ~2GB of my 8GB Laptop,  But it could be anything else.

But my other question still remain unsolvable by me. Please take a look.
Link: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74585315/20603322)

Comment: When posting code in an answer, format as code to make it easier to read.